# Why do I have almost no water pressure after installing a new kitchen faucet?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet, water-pressure

I installed a Price Pfister 533 single control kitchen faucet today, and for whatever reason my water pressure is next to nothing. It was perfectly fine before.

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: i googled *Price pfister 533* and the first link returned was the Pfister's troubleshooting FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

When you turn off your water valves or replace a faucet it is very common to kick up sediments in your pipes.  Most water pressure issues are because of these sediments getting stuck in the tap filter.  Look at your directions to unscrew the bottom of your faucet head.  Clean out the filter inside and screw back on head.

Comment: I've also seen the sediment lodge in the water supply shut off valve (usually the hot), with chunks from galvanized steel piping.

Comment: Undersink shut-off valves are notorious. Problem could be that when re-opening the valves, the valve stems snapped off in the closed or near-closed position. Unlikely 2 at-once, and more likely to have been uncloseable in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a single value faucets. I tried a number of things - cleaning is the aerator, flushing the lines. Nothing worked.

So I ended up running the hot line so much it got hot and became unclogged. The cold was still clogged, so I switched the cold line to the hot source. The hot water unclogged the blockage inside the faucet.